# How can I use people's configuration on github to my Neovim?

Tags: github, text-editor, neovim

I love the looks of Neovim in Devsalife's videos. But It's pretty hard for me to follow him since he doesn't talk in most videos. And me trying to use neovim ( And I faced a lot of troubles) which makes me pretty hopeless on using neovim.

I practised neovim enough in VSCode. Now I want to switch to neovim. But it's configuration is too hard ( espcially with Lua ). So I just wanted the fastest way ( which is to copy people's config and use it immedietly, which is Devslife here)

Do you guys have any idea to do this on Windows ? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no short path to get a beautiful Neovim UI. You should understand each line of your configurations.

Of course, someone can create a guide with a full setup, from how to install Neovim, and set up Plugins and dependencies but I haven't found anyone who does it yet. I'm trying to write a detail guide but it hasn't finished so I can't share it now.

However, I can tell you some steps to create a Neovim configuration yourself:

- Install Neovim, of course
- Install a packet manager (**Packer**, **Vim plug**) and learn how to use it
- Theme (**gruvbox, dracula**): make your Neovim look good first
- File explorer (**nerdtree**)
- For coding

  - LSP (**nvim-lspconfig**): for autocompletion, diagnostic,..
  - Format code (**neoformat**): format your code based on the convention
- Other

  - Vim features

    - Folding (foldmethod)
    - Spell checking
  - Icon for files (**vim-devicons**)
  - Find files (**telescope.nvim**)
  - Git manager (**vim-fugitive**)
  - Beautify the tabline (**lualine.nvim**)
  - Surround fast action (**vim-surround**)

If you have any specific problem while setting up your Neovim, Stackoverflow is available

Comment: Oh thanks, Welp we have to go through the pain for now...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome in the Neovim world :)

To begin with a Neovim configuration in Lua, you can see some good repositories :

- **Nvim basic IDE** https://github.com/LunarVim/nvim-basic-ide
- **Neovim from scratch** https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch
  and the **Youtube playlist** associated https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctH-a-1eUME&list=PLhoH5vyxr6Qq41NFL4GvhFp-WLd5xzIzZ

You can also use Neovim configuration bundles :

- **LunarVim** https://www.lunarvim.org/
- **AstroNvim** https://astronvim.github.io/
- **SpaceVim** https://spacevim.org/
- **NvChad** https://nvchad.com/

Comment: Not the one I want, but definitely what I need.

To be honest, thanks for guiding me to the Neovim world ( where I just want to impress the girls lol )